# SQL for Select By Attribute to only select Feature Class Polygons based on values from a Table

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql, select-by-attribute, table, feature-class

I have a polygon feature class with one of the attributes being Parcel ID Numbers (Parcels_in_City).

I have a table with only Parcel ID Numbers (Parcels_with_Trees).

Is there a SQL query that can be used in the Select By Attribute tool that will select all of the Parcel ID Numbers from Parcels_in_City based on the values in the Parcels_with_Trees table?

Comment: The relationship is One to one.

Comment: Have you tried creating an in-map join and using the select by attributes dialog to write a query on the joined fields?

Comment: Yes and that was my original solution. At this point, I am only wondering if there is another process where instead I could use SQL in the Select By Attribute tool to perform the same action instead of using a Join and then Select By Attribute.

Comment: What about using a subquery in the expression? `[FIELD_NAME] In (SELECT [FIELD_NAME] FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [FIELD_NAME] = xyz)`. Inspired by this page:  [How To: Query for duplicate records in a feature class table](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006708).

Comment: Or what about creating a database view or a query layer?

Comment: Using the subquery didn't work out but I am looking into more related to the article that you linked. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why didn't the subquery work for you? I've had good success with subqueries in Oracle GDBs.